# Date format(AM\PM) in Vietnamese

Tags: android, locale, simpledateformat, datetime-format

I'm trying to show the lokalize date to Chinese and Vietnamese.But somehow AM/PM is not translating to Vietnamese.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("vi","VN");
String p1 = "MMM dd, yyy 'at' h:mm a";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(p1, locale);
```

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. On my desktop Java 9 I get `thg 11 12, 2019 at 8:25 SA`. I cannot tell whether SA is Vietnamese, but it doesn’t appear to be English. Which result are you getting on Android? And on which Android version or API level?

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, uuuu 'at' h:mm a", new Locale("vi", "VN"));
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.of(2021, 8, 4, 10, 20).format(dtf));
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.of(2021, 8, 4, 20, 30).format(dtf));
    }
}
```

**Output from a sample run:**

```
thg 8 04, 2021 at 10:20 SA
thg 8 04, 2021 at 8:30 CH
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Nlp2Pk)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show `AM/PM` then you will try with `Locale.ENGLISH`:

```
Locale locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
String p1 = "MMM dd, yyy 'hiat' h:mm a";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(p1, locale);
```

Comment: I want to show the AM/PM in Vietnamese not as English string.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who still searching for this topic, I have written it manually. I upload [my file here](https://gist.github.com/dzungvu/d0841aaa829ecac37b76ef4f06ae2bbe) for you in case you don't want to write it.

Usage:

```
val spf = SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd/MM/yy hh:mm a", Locale.US)
val dateStr = spf.formatToVN(date)
```